# Какая кнопка вызвала функцию

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

У меня есть окно *tkinter*. 
В нем создано много кнопок (`btn1`, `btn2`, `btn3`, ...), у которых при нажатии вызывается одна и та же функция.

Как функции понять, какой кнопкой она была вызвана? 
К примеру, изменить текст кнопки.

```
def test:
   ...[“text”] = “Clicked!”
  ## вместо точек должна быть нажатая кнопка

btn1 = Button(text=“”,command=test)
btn2 = Button(text=“”,command=test)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Добавила код :))

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def test(btn):
    print(f'def test: {btn["text"]}')
    btn["text"] = "Clicked!"
   

btn1 = Button(root, text="Btn1")#.grid(row=0, sticky=W)
btn1.config(command=lambda: test(btn1))
btn1.grid(row=0, sticky=W)

btn2 = Button(root, text="Btn2")
btn2.config(command=lambda: test(btn2))
btn2.grid(row=1, sticky=W)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]