# Некорректно работает кнопка в tkinter python 3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Хочу отрисовать сетку 16x16 для игры в крестики-нолики.

```py
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Крестики-нолики")
window.geometry("800x650")

iszero = False

def clc():
    global iszero
    if iszero == False:
        btn["text"] = "x"
        iszero = True
    else:
        btn["text"] = "o"
        iszero = False


for i in range(1, 17):
    for j in range(1, 17):
        btn = tk.Button(window, width=5, height=2, command=clc)
        btn.grid(column=i, row=j)

window.mainloop()
```

Почему-то при запуске этого кода текст меняется не на нажатой кнопке, а на одной и той же, которая находится в углу.

Comment: Логично, потому что вы в переменную `btn` положили одну-единственную кнопку — ту, которая осталась после выполнения последней итерации циклов

Comment: Подозреваю, что связанный вопрос: [Какая кнопка вызвала функцию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1179846) (правда, идеально подходящих ответов там не видно)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74914372/how-to-change-the-color-of-panedwindow-upon-hovering-over-it-for-multiple-paned/74917587#74917587

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что Вы создаете **одну** кнопку и в цикле постоянно меняете её значение. В результате переменная *btn* хранит значение последней созданной кнопки (которая и находится в правом нижнем углу).

Итак:

- Для удобства лучше хранить размер поля в переменной (например *size = 16*)
- Далее, Вам нужно создать матрицу 16x16 из кнопок (*btns = [[0 for x in range(size)] for y in range(size)]*)
- И для **каждой** кнопки из матрицы указать какой аргумент передавать в функцию-обработчик (*clc*); обычно это делают через lambda-функции

В итоге, такой код:

```
       import tkinter as tk
        
        window = tk.Tk()
        window.title("Крестики-нолики")
        window.geometry("800x650")
        
        iszero = False
        
        def clc(index):
            global iszero
            i, j = index
            if iszero == False:
                btns[i][j]["text"] = "x"
                iszero = True
            else:
                btns[i][j]["text"] = "o"
                iszero = False
        
        
        size = 16
        btns = [[0 for x in range(size)] for y in range(size)]
        
        for i in range(size):
            for j in range(size):
                btn_clc = lambda x = (i, j): clc(x)
                btns[i][j]= tk.Button(window, width=5, height=2, command=btn_clc)
                btns[i][j].grid(column=i, row=j)
        
        window.mainloop()
```